# c# Credit payments calculator

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

I made a program for calculating credits payments in C#, but I have some problem. Initially, I made a class,

```
public class Rate
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public double Principal { get; set; }
    public double Interest { get; set; }
    public double Insurance { get; set; }
    public int Commission { get; set; }
    public double TotalPayment { get; set; }
    public double CreditValue { get; set; }
}
```

After, I made another class, `Data Context`, which creates a list of Rates. I don't know how to create this list, for using later in a binding source for a data grid. In data grid form, i have some radio button and six text boxes for setting equal/descending payments, Credit Value, duration of credit(in month = number of rates), interest  (%), insurance (%), commission analysis, monthly commission (%) and a button Calculate. After taking this value i need to calculate the payments and to show in data grid.
 Any idea how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create the list like this

```
public ObservableCollection<Rate> MyList { get; set; }
```

and

```
public void InitializeMyList()
{
    MyList = new ObservableCollection<Rate>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        MyList.Add(new Rate() { ID = i, Interest = 2.0, Insurance = 0.5 });
    }
}
```

Then bind to it like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}"/>
```

You can also define columns like this

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Interest}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Insurance}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

This [tutorial](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/WPFDataGrid.aspx) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760838/create-a-custom-datagrids-itemssource) may be helpful too.