# Loading json from api in Datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to load specific data from my api into datagrid.
I make requests for specific Id, and the results should be appear in data grid

Here's my code behind :

```
private async void btnSearch_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
      {
          try
          {
              string url = string.Format("https://localhost:44324/api/Channels/{0}", idtxt.Text);
              var json = client.DownloadString(url);

              Channelindex info = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Channelindex>(json);

           

              txtName.Text = info.name;
              txturl.Text=info.url;
              Usergrid. Itemsource=info.url;
                

              MessageBox.Show("User Found : " + info.name + " " + info.url);

          }
          catch (Exception ex)
          {
               MessageBox.Show("Unable To Locate ID: " + ex.Message, "Exception Sample", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);

          }
    }
}
```

But my datagrid fails.
I'd appreciate if you help me
Thanks.

Comment: Thanks very much. It worked

Comment: would you be so kind and mark the answer as "best answer"?!

Answer (score 0):

As your code suggest `Channelindex info` is an object with a property of `url` being a string.
This is not a valid `ItemsSource` (not `Itemsource`). It should be a list of items.

Without more code it's hard to tell, but I would suggest

```
Usergrid.ItemsSource = new string[] { info.url };
```

or

```
Usergrid.ItemsSource = new[] { info };
```

and then specify a column definition to pick `url`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/10761291/394076 for more info